# How do I set a class if entry is a child of a particular parent?

Tags: structure

I have a structure section which is three levels deep and I want to add a class when the entry has a parent id of X. I am trying something like:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('brand').descendantOf(entry.id).level(3) %}
<li class="nav--brand__item{% if entry.isAncestorOf(13) %} cs-g{% endif %}">
  ...
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a "Recoverable error":

> Argument 1 passed to Craft\BaseElementModel::isAncestorOf() must be an
>   instance of Craft\BaseElementModel, string given

What am I doing wrong?

Updated code:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('brand').descendantOf(entry.id).level(3) %}
{% set entryWithId13 = craft.entries.id(13).first() %}
{% set entryWithId23 = craft.entries.id(23).first() %}
{% set entryWithId23 = craft.entries.id(29).first() %}
<li class="nav--brand__item{% if entryWithId13.isAncestorOf(entry) %} cs-h{% endif %}{% if entryWithId23.isAncestorOf(entry) %} cs-k{% endif %}{% if entryWithId29.isAncestorOf(entry) %} cs-h{% endif %}">
...
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out using the following code. Not sure if I could make the conditional neater but this achieves what I need:

```twig
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('brand').descendantOf(entry.id).level(3) %}
{% set parentId = entry.getParent().id %}
<li class="nav--brand__item{% if parentId == 13 %} cs-g{% endif %}{% if parentId == 23 %} cs-k{% endif %}{% if parentId == 29 %} cs-h{% endif %}">
  ...
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test whether `entry-with-id-X` is an ancestor of `entry`, do this (assuming x = 13):

```
{% set entryWithIdX = craft.entries.id(13).first() %}
...
{% if entryWithIdX.isAncestorOf(entry) %} ... {% endif %}
{# or #}
{% if entry.isDescendantOf(entryWithIdX) %} ... {% endif %}
```

[isAncestorOf](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#isAncestorOf) and [isDescendantOf](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#isDescendantOf) take an entry as parameter, not an entryId.

It would be a good idea to test to see whether `craft.entries.id(13)` returns anything before calling `first()` on it, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Hi Marion, I am not sure I completely follow. I have pasted in what I now have which doesn't work.